# Find second word based on position of first word in a string

Tags: python, loops, find

I am trying to locate a word based on the position of a different word i.e.

```
second_word = "KEGG"
first_word_position = 35
```

How do I locate the position of my second word by looking near the position of my first word. The reason for this being there are many duplicates of my second word that I am looking for, but only a single value for the first word I have located. The purpose of this being to parse through a webpage and locate annotation date for specific reactions.

Comment: I imagine you would find the second word by the same process you used to find the first one...

Comment: If I use the find function it simply returns the first instance of the second word, instead of the second word nearest to the first word's position